# SlowCheetah working in VS but not from command line

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, slowcheetah

I have an Azure cloud service, with a web role and a worker.

I have a problem with the worker role when I create the Package from the command line.
My worker is a simple class Library with a App.Config and transformation are made with SlowCheetah 2.5.5.

If I right click on my Azure Cloud Service and Package it everything is fine, the app.config in the end will be the one transformed by SlowCheetah as you can see below

```
22>Target "CopyWorkerRoleFiles" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.0\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" from project "C:\dev\My\WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.ccproj" (target "CopyRoleFiles" depends on it):
22> WorkerFiles=C:\dev\My\MyWorker\bin\QA\MyWorker.dll.config -> MyWorker.dll.config
22> WorkerFiles=C:\dev\My\MyWorker\obj\QA\MyWorker.dll -> MyWorker.dll
22> WorkerFiles=C:\dev\My\MyWorker\obj\QA\MyWorker.pdb -> MyWorker.pdb
22> WorkerFiles=C:\dev\My\MyWorker\obj\QA\SlowCheetah\App.config -> MyWorker.dll.config
```

From command line, now, when I create the package, SlowCheetah is not used anymore and I don't have the transformation

```
CopyWorkerRoleFiles:
WorkerFiles=C:\CI\My\MyWorker\bin\QA\MyWorker.dll.config -> MyWorker.dll.config
WorkerFiles=C:\CI\My\MyWorker\bin\QA\App.config -> App.config
WorkerFiles=C:\CI\My\MyWorker\obj\QA\MyWorker.dll -> MyWorker.dll
WorkerFiles=C:\CI\My\MyWorker\obj\QA\MyWorker.pdb -> MyWorker.pdb
```

How can I find what I am missing to have the same behavior between VS and the command line?

**EDIT:**

I have created a small cloud project with one worker role and slowcheetah, and everything is working fine on this new project...
The problem is coming from my project, I have doubled check the csproj and ccproj from my solution with the ones from the test solution and I don't see any big difference...

**EDIT 2:**

Here is my msbuild command to compile my project

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe .\MyProject.sln 
/p:Configuration=QA /p:TargetProfile=CloudQA /target:Publish /nr:false
```

**EDIT 3:**
I finally narrowed the problem to this, I have updated Microsoft.Bcl to 1.1.3, I compiled it, the transformation works fine!

I have updated Microsoft.Net.Http to 2.2.13, I compiled it, the transformation failed.

The nuget packages added this to my csproj...

```
      <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
 +    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Extensions">
 +      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.13\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
 +    </Reference>
      <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
 +    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Primitives">
 +      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.13\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
 +    </Reference>
 +    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest" />
```

If I remove all the references the transformation is working again...

I added back this reference and the transformation was still working:

```
 +    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest" />
```

I added this references one by one

```
 +    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Extensions">
 +      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.13\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
 +    </Reference>
 +    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Primitives">
 +      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.13\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
 +    </Reference>
```

And the project transformation failed again.

**EDIT 4:**

More information on this problem, Micorosoft.Net.HttpClient Nuget Packages is also modifying the app.config when System.Net.Http.Extensions and System.Net.Http.Primitives. It adds the following to app.config

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Extensions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.13.0" newVersion="2.2.13.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.13.0" newVersion="4.2.13.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Here is the build output with these assemblies referenced

```
17>_CopyAppConfigFile:
17>  Copying file from "obj\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.csproj.App.config" to "bin\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.dll.config".
17>CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
17>  Copying file from "obj\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.dll" to "bin\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.dll".
17>  Tests.MyProject.Data -> C:\dev\MyProject\Tests\Tests.MyProject.Data\bin\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.dll
17>  Copying file from "obj\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.pdb" to "bin\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.pdb".
17>ScReplaceAppConfigItem:
17>  Updated app.config to point to transformed file
17>      AppConfigWithTargetPath: obj\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.csproj.App.config
17>      AppConfigWithTargetPath.TargetPath: Tests.MyProject.Data.dll.config
```

Removing the Microsoft references

```
17>_CopyAppConfigFile:
17>  Copying file from "App.config" to "bin\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.dll.config".
17>CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
17>  Copying file from "obj\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.dll" to "bin\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.dll".
17>  Tests.MyProject.Data -> C:\dev\MyProject\Tests\Tests.MyProject.Data\bin\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.dll
17>  Copying file from "obj\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.pdb" to "bin\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.pdb".
17>ScReplaceAppConfigItem:
17>  Copying file from "bin\Debug\Tests.MyProject.Data.dll.config" to "obj\Debug\SlowCheetah\App.config".
17>  Updated app.config to point to transformed file
17>      AppConfigWithTargetPath: obj\Debug\SlowCheetah\App.config
17>      AppConfigWithTargetPath.TargetPath: Tests.MyProject.Data.dll.config
```

Comment: Can you provide the command that you are executing?

Comment: Hello Sayed, FYI, I have recreated a solution with all my project and it's working there with the same build command...

Comment: Do you have any idea where I should start to debug this issue? Thanks

Comment: Build both from the command line and compare the build log to see what is happening.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi I have just encountered this problem again... Yesterday everything was working fine, I've updated nuget packages for Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Net.Http. I have the same error. Do you have an idea of what may goes wrong?

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi I have updated my post with EDIT 3! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with Slowcheetah 2.5.7